# Angular do json properly

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'm facing a little issue

This is my `app.js`:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.skillz = {
    "animaux": [
      { text: "Assistance comptable", checked: true },
      { text: "conciergerie", checked: false },
      { text: "Conciergerie", checked: false },
      { text: "Conseil fiscal et impots", checked: false },
    ],
    "barimaux": [
      
      { text: "Assistance comptable", checked: false },
      { text: "conciergerie", checked: false },
      { text: "Conciergerie", checked: false },
    ]
  }
})
```

In my output I want something who look like this

- Animaux

  - assistance compatable
  - conciergerie
  - conseil
- Barimaux

  - assistance compatable
  - conciergerie
  - conseil

Anyone knows how I can do that?

Regards

Comment: i used ng-repeat but the text is skillz text is not displayed 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOBPVp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this updated [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbzwWa)

html code:

```
<body ng-app="ionicApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, skill) in skillz" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">{{key}}</li>
      <ul ng-repeat="s in skill" >

        <li> <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="ssss"  ng-value="{{s.checked}}" ng-checked="s.checked">{{s.text}}</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

js code:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.skillz = {
      animaux: [{
          text: "Assistance comptable",
          checked: true
        }, {
          text: "conciergerie",
          checked: false
        }, {
          text: "Conciergerie",
          checked: false
        }, {
          text: "Conseil fiscal et impots",
          checked: false
        },

      ],
      barimaux: [

        {
          text: "Assistance comptable",
          checked: false
        }, {
          text: "conciergerie",
          checked: false
        }, {
          text: "Conciergerie",
          checked: false
        },
      ]


    }

  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="item item-divider skillz" ng-repeat="(key, skill) in skillz" 
   style="background-color:#01c0f7; color: white">
    {{key}}
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="s.checked" ng-checked="s.checked" ng-repeat="s in skill">
      {{s.text}}
    </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOBPxp?editors=101)

Comment: that's what i'm doin but the text skillz text is not displayed
please see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOBPVp

Comment: that's works perfectly thank you but broke the divider because the div is not closed properly

Comment: you don't want that divider between two checkboxes group?

Comment: i want that divider , but its supposed to take just the title box ; now its taking all the box , with the blue color